# Cancel scan for an ip in interval

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to stop the execution of function if ip in range takes more than 2 seconds.

```
from certifier import CertInfo

def fun(i):
    ip = f"x.x.x.{i}"
    cert = CertInfo(ip, 443)
    issuer = cert.info()["issuer"]
    print(ip, issuer[1][0][1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, 254):
        fun(i)
    print("Scan completed :)")
```

I tried multiprocessing, threading, stopit, timeout-decorator but couldn't solve the problem. If connection attempt fails, it takes too long to raise error.

Comment: Please, *show what you tried*.